# Running rails s after gem update returns list of warnings - warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_AIO_LISTIO_MAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, warnings

I just tried to update my gem library with command `gem update` and updating finished smooth.

After that I updated version of my rails project in Gemfile from `6.0.1` to `6.0.3` and after running `rails s` I got a list of warnings:

```
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::VERSION
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fileutils-1.4.1/lib/fileutils.rb:105: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_AIO_LISTIO_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_AIO_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_AIO_PRIO_DELTA_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_ARG_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_ATEXIT_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_BC_BASE_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_BC_DIM_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_BC_SCALE_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_BC_STRING_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_CHILD_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_CLK_TCK
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_COLL_WEIGHTS_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_DELAYTIMER_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_EXPR_NEST_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_HOST_NAME_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_IOV_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_LINE_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_LOGIN_NAME_MAX
/home/zire/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_NGROUPS_MAX
```

First line issue I fixed with uninstalling fileutilis with  `gem uninstall fileutils` and running `gem update --default`

Now I have problem with rest of warning lines. Is there any solution there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution after running `bundle update` command I also run `bundle clean --force` and on the next run of `rails s` command all warnings disappears.